# How do i get which spot in a 3D world has been clicked in libGdx

Tags: java, 3d, libgdx

I am trying to create a 3d world that behaves similarly to minecraft where a player can look in 360 degrees and if he trys to click on a spot (X,Y,Z coordinate in the 3D world), the model being drawn there gets deleted. I am very new to programming a 3D world in LibGdx so any help is useful. I do camera rotation with this:

```
float deltaX = -Gdx.input.getDeltaX() * player.degreesPerPixel;
float deltaY = -Gdx.input.getDeltaY() * player.degreesPerPixel;
    if(deltaX>0)
        player.camera.rotate(Vector3.Z, (float)1.5);
    else if(deltaX<0)
        player.camera.rotate(Vector3.Z, (float)-1.5);
player.tmp.set(player.camera.direction).crs(player.camera.up).nor();
player.camera.direction.rotate(player.tmp, deltaY);
player.setDir(player.camera.direction.x, player.camera.direction.y);
```

Thank you

Comment: OK, so what's actually your question? Surely it wouldn't really be rewarding enough for you to just ask and get ready code...

Comment: How do  i go about creating the code for it. I am not asking for the code because that does not teach me, but i do not have an idea of how to go about coding it. So while the code would work, a guide/walk through would be better

Answer (score 2):

In a 2D environment, you would usually just use `Camera.unproject(...)`, which takes some screenspace point and transforms that back into gameworld coordinates.

In 3D it's not that easy, because of the additional dimension adding some depths to your world. That's why a click on the 2D plane (your screen) could hit basically infinitely many points in the 3D world. In libgdx, this *ray* of possibly clicked points is called the pick-ray.

If you want the intersection point on a certain plane, the code could look like his:

```
public void hitSomething(Vector2 screenCoords) {
    // If you are only using a camera
    Ray pickRay = camera.getPickRay(screenCoords.x, screenCoords.y);
    // If your camera is managed by a viewport
    Ray pickRay = viewport.getPickRay(screenCoords.x, screenCoords.y);

    // we want to check a collision only on a certain plane, in this case the X/Z plane
    Plane plane = new Plane(new Vector3(0, 1, 0), Vector3.Zero);
    Vector3 intersection = new Vector3();
    if (Intersector.intersectRayPlane(pickRay, plane, intersection)) {
        // The ray has hit the plane, intersection is the point it hit
    } else {
        // Not hit
    }
}
```

In your case, when you have a minecraft-like world, your code could look like the following:

```
public void hitSomething(Vector2 screenCoords) {
    Ray pickRay = ...;

    // A bounding box for each of your minecraft blocks
    BoundingBox boundingBox = new BoundingBox();
    Vector3 intersection = tmp;
    if (Intersector.intersectRayBounds(pickRay, boundingBox, intersection)) {
        // The ray has hit the box, intersection is the point it hit
    } else {
        // Not hit
    }
}
```

Please not that in a minecraft world there are literally thousands of such blocks. Going this simple approach would not be very fast. You will probably have to end up with a hierarchical solution, that first checks big chunks (bounding boxes that include many blocks) for a possible hit, and then start checking individual blocks.

Comment: how do you manage the boundingBox for each block in the 3d array? 
and to get the X,Y,Z i can just do intersection.x, intersection.y, intersection.z so that i could put those coordinates into my 3d array?
Also thank you for helping me understand this

Comment: Which 3D array are you talking about?

Comment: My map is stored in a 3D char array called world. My goal is to make it so that when a player right clicks, they destroy the char there. So if a player mines a piece of dirt it switches that map location from a 'd' to a ' ' but I would need access to the X,Y,Z coordinates from where the person clicked.

Comment: @Burf2000 Why do you think that my given solution would not work?

Comment: Sorry I was just checking he got it working, I managed to fix mine here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31805868/libgdx-detecting-where-a-ray-hits-a-3d-object?noredirect=1#comment51559869_31805868